# R remove s at the end of each word

Tags: r, lapply, text-mining, gsub

I've got the following R code:

```
temp <- strsplit(unlist(test_data$`Product Description`), split=" ")
temp <- lapply(temp, function(x) gsub("s$", '', x))
```

What I'm trying to do is to strip out the s at the end of every word in the 'Product Description' Column.

The first step of the code works perfectly and it splits the data as it should by creating a list of words per description.

However, the second step does not work. It does not strip out the 's'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sub` with the pattern `(.*)s$`, and then replace with the first capture group.

```
temp <- lapply(temp, function(x) sub("(.*)s$", '\\1', x))
```

The idea here is that if the pattern does match, we will replace with the final `s` stripped off.  If the pattern does not match, then `sub` would just return the entire untouched string.

### Demo